# How to retrieve data from influxdb RAM efficiently (without loading whole database in RAM)?

Tags: python-3.x, database, time-series, influxdb

I am performing operation with operation at large scale, with a billion data point. while I was inserting data into the database it overloaded my swap memory and then laptop freeze. I tried changing index type to "ts1" from "inmem" from config file then I was able to insert data with less swap memory usage.

Now when I start retrieving data even a single datapoint using below query it overloads RAM. Because of large RAM usage

```
SELECT s1 FROM m1 limit 1
```

When I further explored this problem I found that influxdb is inmemory database in order to optimize the performance. Is there any way to perform retrieve.

I am doing this operation via influxdb-python(5.3.1) package. Influxdb version(1.8.9)

Comment: Presumably the same query fails when you run using the command-line ```influx``` tool.  This would confirm what you have already indicated, that this has nothing to do with python. You might be stuck with either needing a bigger computer or to adjust influx's retention policy to drop some points.

Comment: yaa problem is not with python but with influxdb. I want to do it in same RAM, I also can't reduce data points, so the only remaining option is to try change retention policy. It does't seems intuitively that reducing retention policy can reduce the ram usage. because according to my understanding retention policy determine for how much duration data will stay in data

Comment: Perhaps if you do the down-sampling within influx with the appropriate retention policy, so that influx only keeps the data in a reduced form.

Comment: ok I can try that, but Is there any way influxdb manages data with RAM and secondary storage so that it optimize memory usage by changing configuration of influxdb ?

Comment: It would be great if a sample of the ingested data is present in the question. This will help determining the source of high memory usage at InfluxDB. BTW, did you try other solutions, which support data ingestion with InfluxDB line protocol? They may need lower amounts of memory. See, for example, https://valyala.medium.com/insert-benchmarks-with-inch-influxdb-vs-victoriametrics-e31a41ae2893